# Can we convert the optimization of a loss function with regularization to the Lagrangian, constrained optimization *before* solving the optimization?

Tags: regularization, loss-functions, lagrange-multipliers, constrained-optimization

It is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335306/why-are-additional-constraint-and-penalty-term-equivalent-in-ridge-regression) that the optimization of a loss function with regularization,

$$\text{argmin}_b L(X,b) + c ||b||_p \phantom{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa} (*)$$

is equivalent to  the constrained optimization

$$\text{argmin}_b L(X,b), \phantom{aaa}\text{under constraint} ||b||_p \leq r \phantom{aaaaaaaa} (**)$$

where $r \geq ||b_{opt}||_p$ and $b_{opt}$ solves $(*)$ via the Lagrangian.

This implies that when presented with the optimization $(*)$, one has to solve it (find $b_{opt}$), in order to write down the constraint ($r$) in $(**)$.

When presented with $(*)$ (when ready to train an ML model in particular), I would like to know before solving for the optimal parameters if we can determine $r$, the constrained version $(**)$. My goal is to limit my search space *before* doing the original optimization $(*)$.

Can this be done? If it depends on $p$, the norm used, I am most interested in $p= 1,2$.